# HOW TO APPLY DIFFERENT FILTERS ON DIFFERENT EXPRESSIONS?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-tablix

I have a report with two parameters: StartDate and EndDate.

I have a table including province name and for each province need to calculate:

1. Balance at at StartDate
2. Sum of credit and debit between StartDate and EndDate
3. Balance in EndDate

As each expression should work with filters, I don’t know how to handle it in SSRS?

Comment: The easiest way (usually) is to pass the parameters to your dataset query and work everything out there, then just SSRS to display the results. Post more info if you need more help. Screenshots of the report design, what you want to look like and sample data that supports your mock-up output. At the moment there is not enough info to go on.

Comment: I suggest to calculate the starting balances in the dataset query, which should join the transactions from the relevant time interval to these results. The rest can be done in the report (using a table with one rowgroup and without a details "group").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the excellent answer by @HannoverFist on how to set this up within your report, you could also do it in your SQL statement to have it calculated on the server (rather than download an entire dataset just to SUM it) like so:

```
SELECT Province, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Record_DATE < @StartDate THEN PayAmt END) AS OpeningBalance,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Record_DATE >= @StartDate AND Record_DATE <= @EndDate THEN PayAmt END) AS PeriodBalance,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Record_DATE <= @EndDate THEN PayAmt END) AS ClosingBalance
FROM ProvincePaymentsTable
GROUP BY Province
ORDER BY Province
```

(using Sql Server syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Add grouping to your table on Province. Make sure your dataset is ordered in Province order. Delete the Detail row (you don't need it, we just want SUMs) and delete the Group Header. We'll put our data in the Group Footer.

First column is simply the Province name.

The second column is the Opening Balance (prior to the Start Date) and so we SUM it IIF the date is less than the Start Date using this expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Record_DATE.Value < Parameters!StartDate.Value,
         Fields!PayAmt.Value, 
         CDEC(0)
         )
    )
```

The third column is the Period Balance (between the two dates) and so we SUM it IIF the date is between the Start Date and the End Date using this expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Record_DATE.Value >= Parameters!StartDate.Value AND Fields!Record_DATE.Value <= Parameters!EndDate.Value,
         Fields!PayAmt.Value, 
         CDEC(0)
         )
    )
```

The last column is the Closing Balance (anything before the End Date) so we SUM it IIF the date is before the End Date using this expression:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Record_DATE.Value <= Parameters!EndDate.Value,
         Fields!PayAmt.Value, 
         CDEC(0)
         )
    )
```